# How can i implement two way asymmetric encryption for my app and backend server?

Tags: algorithms, security, encryption

I'm planning to setup a hybrid encryption procedure in my app. So basically i did encryption for data send from client to server using this method, now i'm confused on how to encrypt data send from server to client. So what i have done so for is that :

I generated a public-private key pair using an asymmetric encryption(RSA), saved the private key in server side and then shipped the public key with my app(client).Now when i need to send data to the server we generate a secret key and then encrypt our data with this secret key. Now we encrypt the secret key using the initially created public key(from asymmetric enc) and send this encrypted secret key and along with the encrypted data to server. Now the server can use its private key to decrypt the secret key and further use the decrypted secret key to decrypt the data

My question is that, how to encrypt the data from server to client using this method? should i create another asymmetric key pair for this, or is there a way to use the existing pair? I'm confused on decrypting part in client side since we can't save the private key in the app

Comment: If I understood it well, you just need to implement HTTPS communication to your web application. To understand how it works, take a look here: https://medium.com/sitewards/the-magic-of-tls-x509-and-mutual-authentication-explained-b2162dec4401

Comment: "I'm planning to setup a hybrid encryption procedure in my app. " - there's a 99% chance you've made a mistake right here.

Comment: @EmersonCardoso i have already implemented an https communication.So in a payments app, if there is a pen test by the bank team, this will be approved right?

Comment: @NavneetKrishna, Yes, provided you have restricted the TLS protocols and ciphers to only a known strong subset.  See https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#TLSUsage for a maintained set of strong ciphers.  TLS 1.2 and higher only.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch thanks, currently 1.1 and 1.0 are enabled, i will restrict these